# Issues using psexec -i to launch interactive app

Tags: windows, ssh, psexec

I'm connecting to a windows machine over SSH and would like to launch a GUI app in an existing interactive session.

This should work using `psexec -i`, but it fails for me in various ways:

1. `psexec -i 1 notepad.exe`: notepad crashes without showing UI
2. `psexec -i 1 cmd.exe`: I get a black box the size of a cmd.exe window, it never renders.  If I look at the window title with "alt-tab", it does say this is an [Administrator] process which is not what I expected.
3. `psexec -i 1 <path to vscode>`, it launches successfully but then raises a number of errors related to credential storage.
4. `psexec -s -i 1 cmd.exe`: this launches fine, but the process is running as `nt authority\system`, which is not what I want.
5. `psexec -i 1 -u my_user -p my_pwd <path to vscode>`: this works fine, but I can't require passwords and want to use ssh key-based auth instead.

I've seen a ton of questions/answers where it looks like '-i' works for people so I'm not sure what's going wrong here.  Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside: passing a session ID to `-i` is optional, and using just `-i` defaults to the console session, i.e. in the session of whatever user is physically logged on.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to incorrect session id.
Can you check if the session id is correct, by navigating to users tab in the task manager

[Screenshot of Session ID Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGH8p.png)