# PSEXEC Starts on remote PC but does not execute command

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a command to execute on the remote PC on an interactive session to sent a HotKey to the console. The remote command is PowerShell

```
$wsshell = New-Object -comObject wscript.shell
$wsshell.SendKeys("+{Q}")
```

When I run the psexec on the remote work station - locally, it does send the  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> key and run another application without any issue

However when I run remotely via an interactive session with `-i 2` (2 being session which I can see on the console) with `-s` and `-h` (calling user and remote logged user are administrator on the remote PC)

When I execute the `psexec` remotely, I can interactively see that the powershell is getting executed (can see  .bat file console on the remote PC) but it does not send the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to run the other application.

Any help appreciated - can it be related to Powershell Execution Policy. The Execution Policy is `RemoteSigned`

SMBShare, Fileshare and Print rule is in  place for Domain and enabled

Comment: $wsshell = New-Object -comObject wscript.shell and $wsshell.SendKeys("+{Q}" are two separate lines

Comment: Have you tried creating a script on the remote machine itself to run that SendKeys command, and then calling that script remotely? Does that work/behave differently?

Comment: if I run psexec locally   of the remote pc, it does works as expected . Please note  - problem is in execution  of script on the remote pc -(the .bat file is on the remote pc)

Comment: @mklement0 - Does PowerShell Core with PowerShell Remoting offer a better platform on which to achieve this?

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: @lit, no, PowerShell remoting fundamentally doesn't support commands that run visibly on the target machine. `psexec -i` does seem to support it, but seemingly not in combination with `-s` or `-u`, though I'm puzzled, because existing questions suggest that at least at some point in the past that that worked; please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- The following is based on my own experiments with [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) as of v2.43, and the findings are mostly *not* spelled out in the linked documentation.

  - Also - as of this writing - a recent update to that documentation makes an incorrect claim about `-i` being *required* for interactive console applications / shells with redirected in- and output (where the console window on the *caller* side acts like a terminal for the remotely executing program). Unfortunately, the example calls were also updated based on this misconception.

---

I conclude from the following experiment that what you're trying to do can *not* be done, as of `psexec` v2.43, and as tried on both a Windows 10 and a Windows 11 machine:

The following juxtaposes a *local* invocation using a simple test command with a *remote* one; the test command tries to use `-i` in combination with `-s` to run a PowerShell command visibly *on the target machine*, which, after a delay of 3 seconds sends keystrokes (`exit` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to its own window to auto-close it:

- The *local* call - which doesn't have a `\\<computer>` argument - *does* work:

```bash
# OK, but only without \\<machine>
psexec -i -s -nobanner powershell -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -noexit -c '$wsshell = New-Object -comObject wscript.shell; $wsshell.SendKeys(''exit{ENTER}''); ''Sending keystrokes to exit this session in 3 secs...''; Start-Sleep 3'
```

- By contrast, even though adding `"\\$env:COMPUTERNAME"` combined with `-i` *alone* seems to work (at least when "remoting" to the *same machine*), it is *the addition of `-s`* that breaks the call:

  - Adding `-s` seemingly causes the `-i` option to be *ignored*, so that the command runs *invisibly* on the target machine, with its stdout output getting captured and relayed to the caller.
  - **That said, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71789829/45375) implies that at least at *some point* in the past combining `-i` and `-s` (as well as `-i` and `-u`, which my experiments suggest also no longer works) *did* work and, per your feedback, *still does work for you in v2.43*, and that the only problem you saw was that the *keypress-sending part* of the interactive remote execution didn't work** - if anyone has any insights, please let us know.

```bash
# NOT OK, due to combination of \\<machine> with -s 
# (without -s, i.e. with ONLY -i, it works, at least on the same machine)
psexec "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME" -i -s -nobanner powershell -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -noexit -c '$wsshell = New-Object -comObject wscript.shell; $wsshell.SendKeys(''exit{ENTER}''); ''Sending keystrokes to exit this session in 3 secs...''; Start-Sleep 3'
```

Comment: thanks for all feedback, hard work gone to all these research, locally it was working fine.                                    After having exhausted all  option , I have another solution working. Using on screen key board , which will called in via piautogui - using locateOnCenterScreen - which will return me the center of the Shift Key and Q - I am still using psexec to call python  script on the remote work station.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a workaround, @GeoV. Does this mean that you're now using `-i` _without `-s`_ in combination with the on-screen keyboard solution? When I tried `-i` across machines, the visible window on the target machine would render _all black_, and trying what past posts recommended to fix this - adding`-u` or `-s` - did _not_ help, because in my case this caused `-i` to be ignored altogether, as noted in the answer.

Comment: -i and -s flag does work for me for remote execution, the local user is an admin on the remote pc

Comment: using latest version of psexec

Comment: Thanks, @GeoV. So I gather that that means that the window did show up as intended on the target machine and that only the keypress-sending part didn't work?

Comment: that is correct, I am trying to run  some of desktop flows of Power Automate, which is a microsoft product , flows can be run locally on  the desktop using hotkeys, so it may be a microsoft restrection